# Grails not preserving my DB data

Tags: grails

I am building a small Grails application, and I am trying to make the data persist between server restarts in the development environment.

I changed the relevant part of DataSource.groovy to the following:

```
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
        url = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:devDB"
    }
}
```

Every time I restart the server, all the data has disappeared. Am I missing another configuration?

I have tried it both with and without sample data in BootStrap.groovy (if that makes any difference).

Comment: ... which version of Grails are you using?

Comment: @vector Thanks, I removed the 'mem' keyword. All working now.

Comment: ... so I posted is as an answer then :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

... try dropping the 'mem' part of your url string: jdbc:hsqldb:devDB Right now you're running the db in memory mode, hence the loss of data. Running the db in embedded mode should do what you need.

Comment: note that db-create update doesn't delete data. I had create and after removing mem it was deleting data, but realized that db-create update with conjunction with removing mem, solves this issue

Answer (score 1):

You're using an in-memory database, so there's no way for the data survive across server restarts. Switch to a persistent database (MySQL, Postgres, etc.), then set `dbCreate = 'validate'`

For example, assuming you chose MySQL as your database you'll need to change the settings in `DataSource.groovy`to:

```
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "validate"

        // Put the MySQL JDBC JAR on the classpath of your Grails app
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

        // Change these property values as needed
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/yourDB"
        username = "yourUser"
        password = "yourPassword"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your url is configured to use an in-memory database.  That's what the "mem" in your url string refers to.

I find it easier, especially w/ a small project to use BootStrap.groovy in combination w/ dbCreate="create-drop".

You can change your url to point to a file or relational database, though, if you want to persist w/out using BootStrap.groovy.  I'm using grails 2.0 w/ an in memory db.

url = "jdbc:h2:db/devDb;auto_server=true"

Here's an example using mySql (assuming you have a jdbc driver for mysql available):

url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/foo?autoreconnect=true"

An example w/ file:

url = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:prodDb;shutdown=true"

Hope this helps.